# Error connecting to Teradata by Python via teradatasql module || ( failed to follow the required security policy)

Tags: python, teradata

I am trying to connect to Teradata DB via python using teradatasql module. Below is my code which is simple one.

```
    import teradatasql
    import pandas as pd
    
    query="select * from DBC.tablesv sample 10"
    
    with teradatasql.connect(host='<host ip>', user='<username>', password='<password for user>') as connect:
        df = pd.read_sql(query, connect)
    
    print(df.head())
```

But I am getting error message on execution like below. I am a beginner to database programming. Any help from experts will be deeply appreciated.

```
----------------------------------------------------------------

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/data/home/uk393e/anaconda3-5.2.0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 1400, in execute
        cur.execute(*args)
      File "/data/home/uk393e/anaconda3-5.2.0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/teradatasql/__init__.py", line 649, in execute
        self.executemany (sOperation, None, ignoreErrors)
      File "/data/home/uk393e/anaconda3-5.2.0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/teradatasql/__init__.py", line 896, in executemany
        raise OperationalError (sErr)
    teradatasql.OperationalError: [Version 17.0.0.2] [Session 91835188] [Teradata Database] [Error 8056] A message was received that failed to follow the required security policy
     at gosqldriver/teradatasql.(*teradataConnection).formatDatabaseError TeradataConnection.go:1138
     at gosqldriver/teradatasql.(*teradataConnection).makeChainedDatabaseError TeradataConnection.go:1154
     at gosqldriver/teradatasql.(*teradataConnection).processErrorParcel TeradataConnection.go:1217
     at gosqldriver/teradatasql.(*TeradataRows).processResponseBundle TeradataRows.go:1716
     at gosqldriver/teradatasql.(*TeradataRows).executeSQLRequest TeradataRows.go:552
     at gosqldriver/teradatasql.newTeradataRows TeradataRows.go:418
     at gosqldriver/teradatasql.(*teradataStatement).QueryContext TeradataStatement.go:122
     at gosqldriver/teradatasql.(*teradataConnection).QueryContext TeradataConnection.go:2083
     at database/sql.ctxDriverQuery ctxutil.go:48

|
|
|
  File "/data/home/uk393e/anaconda3-5.2.0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/teradatasql/__init__.py", line 896, in executemany
    raise OperationalError (sErr)
pandas.io.sql.DatabaseError: Execution failed on sql: select * from DBC.tablesv
[Version 17.0.0.2] [Session 91835188] [Teradata Database] [Error 8056] A message was received that failed to follow the required security policy
 at gosqldriver/teradatasql.(*teradataConnection).formatDatabaseError TeradataConnection.go:1138
 at gosqldriver/teradatasql.(*teradataConnection).makeChainedDatabaseError TeradataConnection.go:1154
 at gosqldriver/teradatasql.(*teradataConnection).processErrorParcel TeradataConnection.go:1217
 at gosqldriver/teradatasql.(*TeradataRows).processResponseBundle TeradataRows.go:1716
 at gosqldriver/teradatasql.(*TeradataRows).executeSQLRequest TeradataRows.go:552
 at gosqldriver/teradatasql.newTeradataRows TeradataRows.go:418
 at gosqldriver/teradatasql.(*teradataStatement).QueryContext TeradataStatement.go:122
 at gosqldriver/teradatasql.(*teradataConnection).QueryContext TeradataConnection.go:2083
 at database/sql.ctxDriverQuery ctxutil.go:48
 at database/sql.(*DB).queryDC.func1 sql.go:1464
 at database/sql.withLock sql.go:3032
 at database/sql.(*DB).queryDC sql.go:1459
 at database/sql.(*Conn).QueryContext sql.go:1701
 at main.goCreateRows goside.go:652
 at main._cgoexpwrap_212fad278f55_goCreateRows _cgo_gotypes.go:357
 at runtime.call64 asm_amd64.s:574
 at runtime.cgocallbackg1 cgocall.go:316
 at runtime.cgocallbackg cgocall.go:194
 at runtime.cgocallback_gofunc asm_amd64.s:826
 at runtime.goexit asm_amd64.s:2361
unable to rollback
------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in the "Limitations" section of the documentation, the *teradatasql* driver does not yet automatically recognize centrally enforced encryption. You will need to explicitly add the `encryptdata="true"` parameter when invoking the `connect` method.

Comment: Thanks a Fred !
Looks like it helped. It is at least fetching the results from simple queries.

Would you have idea as to how can we store the queries in separate files and refer those in this script. Currently I am storing the SQL in 'query' variable which obviously isn't a good option for large SQLs.

Comment: The SQL request has to be passed as a string. You can of course store queries in separate files and use standard Python to .read the file contents into a string.